# Django: add atributes to filter.fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

How to add placeholder an custom css class atributes to form with filter using django-filters.

**filter.py**

```
class PlaceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Places
        fields = ['name']
```

**html**

```
<form method="GET"> 
    {{ filter.form.name }}
    <label for="name"></label>              
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found solution

```
class PlaceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Search place', 'class': 'input__search'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Places
        fields = ['name']
```